# Porque me sale este error cuando obtengo listado por medio del servicio, "objectDisposedException"?

Tags: c#, wcf

cuando la base de datos tiene data regular no habia ningun problema , pero cuando fue creciendo se cae y solo muestra excepcion "objectDisposedException".

este es la consulta realizada

```
var listaPersona = service.GetPersona_SelectAll_Complete().Where(p => p.PersonaEstado == true).ToList(); 

    var listaImage = service.GetPersona_Select_Img_bytes().ToList();
```

de antemano gracias..[image: ESTOS SON LAS EXCEPCIONES QUE MUESTRA]

try { ModuloAdministracionService service = new ModuloAdministracionService();

```
        service.Timeout = 999999999;

        cargar_empleados.Enabled = false;
        int maximo = 1;
        int EmpresaIDS = DCG.m.Common.Globales.EmpresaID;
        prog_datos_web.Value = 1;

        BMarcacion.Inicializa_Movil();

        var  listaComunicacion = service.GetComunicacionAll().ToList();
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
        var listaTipoEquipo = service.GetTipoEquiposAll().ToList();
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
        var listaTipoOperacion = service.GetTipoOperacionAll().ToList();
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
        var listaAccesos = service.GetAccesos().ToList();
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
        var listaUsuario = service.GetUsuarioAll().ToList();
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
        var listaDigitalizacionEmpresa = service.GetBusqueda_Documentos_Empresa_por_Vencer().ToList();
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
        var listaDigitalizacionPersona = service.GetBusqueda_Documentos_Persona_por_Vencer().ToList();
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
        var listaCategoria = service.GetCategoriasAll().ToList();
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
        var listaCargo = service.GetCargosAll().ToList();
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
        var listaEmpresa = service.GetEmpresaAllPersona().ToList();
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
        var listaEmpresaContratada = service.GetEmpresaAllContratdas().ToList();
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
        var listaTerminal = service.GetTerminalesAll().ToList();

        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();

        **var listaPersona = service.GetPersona_SelectAll_Complete().Where(p => p.PersonaEstado == true).ToList();**
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();

        **var listaPersonaImagen = service.GetPersona_Select_Img_bytes();**
        service = new ModuloAdministracionService();

        int cantCom = listaComunicacion.Count;
        int cantTipE =  listaTipoEquipo.Count;
        int cantTipO = listaTipoOperacion.Count;
        int cantAcc =  listaAccesos.Count;
        int cantUsua =  listaUsuario.Count;
        int cantDigE =  listaDigitalizacionEmpresa.Count;
        int cantDigP =  listaDigitalizacionPersona.Count;
        int cantCat =  listaCategoria.Count;
        int cantCar =  listaCargo.Count;
        int cantEmp =  listaEmpresa.Count;
        int cantEmpc =  listaEmpresaContratada.Count;
        int cantTer = listaTerminal.Count;
        int cantPer = listaPersona.Count;

         maximo += cantCom + cantTipE + cantTipO + cantAcc + cantUsua + cantDigE + cantDigP+
            cantCat + cantCar + cantEmp + cantEmpc + cantTer + cantPer;
        prog_datos_web.Maximum = maximo +1;
        prog_datos_web.Minimum = 0;



        //insertar persona al sdf, en sql tienes q poner mas tiempo en respuesta puede modificar? si

        foreach (var item in listaPersona)
        {

            Persona p = new Persona();
            if (m.Common.Globales.todasLasEmpresaa == 0)
            {
                if (item.EmpresaID == EmpresaIDS)
                {
                    p.PersonaID = item.PersonaID;
                    p.PersonaCodigo = item.PersonaCodigo;
                    p.Descripcion1 = item.PersonaNombre;
                    p.Descripcion2 = item.PersonaApellidoPat + " " + item.PersonaApellidoMat;
                    p.PersonaTarjetaProximidad1 = item.PersonaTarjetaProximidad1;
                    p.PersonaTarjetaProximidad2 = item.PersonaTarjetaProximidad2;
                    //p.PersonaEstado = item.PersonaEstado.ToString();
                    p.CargoID = item.CargoID;
                    p.PersonaEstadoDigitalalizacion = item.PersonaEstadoDigitalizar;
                    p.TipoEntidadID = 1;
                    p.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;

                    BPersona.Insertar(p);
                    prog_datos_web.Value += 1;

                }
            }
            else
            {
                p.PersonaID = item.PersonaID;
                p.PersonaCodigo = item.PersonaCodigo;
                p.Descripcion1 = item.PersonaNombre;
                p.Descripcion2 = item.PersonaApellidoPat + " " + item.PersonaApellidoMat;
                p.PersonaTarjetaProximidad1 = item.PersonaTarjetaProximidad1;
                p.PersonaTarjetaProximidad2 = item.PersonaTarjetaProximidad2;
                p.CargoID = item.CargoID;
                //p.PersonaEstado = item.PersonaEstado.ToString();
                p.PersonaEstadoDigitalalizacion = item.PersonaEstadoDigitalizar;
                p.TipoEntidadID = 1;
                p.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;

                BPersona.Insertar(p);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }


        }


        lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Persona registrada Correctamente";

        //insertar  EMPRESA CONTRATADA al sdf

        foreach (var item in listaEmpresaContratada)
        {
            if (m.Common.Globales.todasLasEmpresaa == 0)
            {
                if (item.EmpresaID == EmpresaIDS)
                {
                    EmpresaContratada emc = new EmpresaContratada();
                    emc.EmpresaContratadaID = item.EmpresaContratadaID;
                    emc.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
                    emc.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID = item.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID;
                    emc.EmpresaContratadaDigitalizacionEstado = item.EmpresaContradaDigitalizacionEstado;
                    emc.EmpresaCodigo = item.EmpresaCodigo;
                    emc.TipoEntidadID = 2;
                    //emc.EmpresaContratadaEstado = item.EmpresaContratadaEstado;
                    BEmpresaContrada.Insert_EmpresaContratada(emc);
                    prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                EmpresaContratada emc = new EmpresaContratada();
                emc.EmpresaContratadaID = item.EmpresaContratadaID;
                emc.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
                emc.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID = item.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID;
                emc.EmpresaContratadaDigitalizacionEstado = item.EmpresaContradaDigitalizacionEstado;
                emc.TipoEntidadID = 2;

                emc.EmpresaCodigo = item.EmpresaCodigo;
                //emc.EmpresaContratadaEstado = item.EmpresaContratadaEstado;
                BEmpresaContrada.Insert_EmpresaContratada(emc);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }

        }
        lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Empresa Contrada registrada Correctamente";
        // INSERT TERMINAL AL SDF
        foreach (var item in listaTerminal)
        {
            if (item.FabricanteID == 2)
            {
                Terminal ter = new Terminal();
                ter.TerminalID = item.TerminalID;
                ter.TerminalCodigo = item.TerminalCodigo;
                ter.TerminalDescripcion = item.TerminalDescripcion;
                ter.TipoEquipoID = item.TipoEquipoID;
                ter.TerminalID = item.TerminalID;
                ter.Puerto = item.Puerto;
                ter.AccesoID = item.AccesoID;
                ter.FabricanteID = item.FabricanteID;
                ter.ComunicacionID = item.ComunicacionID;
                ter.TipoOperacionID = item.TipoOperacionID;
                BTerminal.Insertar_Terminal(ter);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }

        }
        lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Persona registrada Terminal";
        //insertar  EMPRESA al sdf

        foreach (var item in listaEmpresa)
        {
            Empresa em = new Empresa();
            em.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
            em.EmpresaCodigo = item.EmpresaCodigo;
            em.EmpresaNombre = item.EmpresaNombre;
            em.CategoriaID = item.CategoriaID;
            BEmpresa.Insert_Empresa(em);
            prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
        }
        // INSERT CI¡OMUNICACION AL SDF
        foreach (var item in listaComunicacion)
        {

            Comunicacion com = new Comunicacion();
            com.ComunicacionID = item.ComunicacionID;
            com.ComunicacionDescripcion = item.ComunicacionDescripcion;

            BComunicacion.Insert_Comunicacion(com);
            prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
        }
        // INSERT CARGO AL SDF
        foreach (var item in listaCargo)
        {

            Cargos com = new Cargos();
            com.CargoID = item.CargoID;
            com.CargoDescripcion = item.CargoDescripcion;

            BCargo.Insert_Cargos(com);
            prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
        }
        // INSERT CATEGORIA AL SDF
        foreach (var item in listaCategoria)
        {

            Categoria com = new Categoria();
            com.CategoriaID = item.CategoriaID;
            com.CategoriaDescripcion = item.CategoriaDescripcion;

            BCategoria.Insertar_Categoria(com);
            prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
        }

        lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Comunicacion registrada Correctamente";
        // INSERT TipoEquipo AL SDF
        foreach (var item in listaTipoEquipo)
        {

            TipoEquipo tipe = new TipoEquipo();
            tipe.TipoEquipoID = item.TipoEquipoID;
            tipe.TipoEquipoDescripcion = item.TipoEquipoDescripcion;

            BTipoEquipo.Insert_TipoEquipo(tipe);
            prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
        }
        lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Tipo Equipo registrada Correctamente";
        // INSERT TipoOperacion AL SDF
        foreach (var item in listaTipoOperacion)
        {

            TipoOperacion tipoo = new TipoOperacion();
            tipoo.TipoOperacionID = item.TipoOperacionID;
            //tipoo.TipoOperacionCodigo = item.TipoOperacionCodigo;
            tipoo.TipoOperacionDescripcion = item.TipoOperacionDescripcion;
            tipoo.TipoOperacionEstado = item.TipoOperacionEstado;

            BTipoOperacion.Insert_TipoOperacion(tipoo);
            prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
        }
        lbl_estado_registro.Text = "TipoOperacion registrada Correctamente";
        // INSERT Accesos AL SDF
        foreach (var item in listaAccesos)
        {

            Accesos acc = new Accesos();
            acc.AccesoID = item.AccesoID;
            acc.AccesoDescripcion = item.AccesoDescripcion;
            BAccesos.Insert_Accesos(acc);
            prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
        }
        lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Accesos registrada Correctamente";
        // INSERT DigitalizacionEmpresa AL SDF
        foreach (var item in listaDigitalizacionEmpresa)
        {

            DigitalizacionEmpresa dem = new DigitalizacionEmpresa();
            dem.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
            dem.EmpresaContratadaID = item.EmpresaContratadaID;
            dem.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID = item.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID;
            dem.DocumentoEmpresaDescripcion = item.DocumentoEmpresaDescripcion;
            dem.DocumentoEmpresaID = item.DocumentoEmpresaID;
            //dem.CategoriaID = item.CategoriaID;
            dem.RegistroID = item.RegistroID;
            dem.Observacion = item.Observacion;
            dem.DiaRestante = item.DiaRestante;

            BDigitalizacionEmpresa.Insert_DigitalizacionEmpresa(dem);
            prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
        }
        lbl_estado_registro.Text = "DigitalizacionEmpresa registrada Correctamente";
        // INSERT TipoOperacion AL SDF
        foreach (var item in listaDigitalizacionPersona)
        {

            DigitalizacionPersona dper = new DigitalizacionPersona();
            dper.PersonaID = item.PersonaID;
            dper.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
            dper.DocumentoPersonaID = item.DocumentoPersonaID;
            dper.DocumentoPersonaDescripcion = item.DocumentoPersonaDescripcion;
            //dper.CategoriaID = item.CategoriaID;
            dper.RegistroID = item.RegistroID;
            dper.Observacion = item.Observacion;
            dper.DiaRestante = item.DiaRestante;

            BDigitalizacionPersona.Insert_DigitalizacionPersona(dper);
            prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
        }
        lbl_estado_registro.Text = "DigitalizacionPersona registrada Correctamente";
        // INSERT TipoOperacion AL SDF

        foreach (var item in listaUsuario)
        {

            Usuario usu = new Usuario();
            usu.UsuarioID = item.UsuarioID;
            usu.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
            usu.UsuarioNombre = item.UsuarioNombre;
            usu.UsuarioPassword = item.UsuarioPassword;
            usu.UsuarioLogin = item.UsuarioLogin;
            usu.UsuarioEmail = item.UsuarioEmail;


            BUsuario.Insertar_Cuenta_Usuario(usu);
            prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
        }

        lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Todas las tablas registrada Correctamente";

        MessageBox.Show("Todas las tablas registrada Correctamente");
        SC_ConfiguracionSDF mcc = new SC_ConfiguracionSDF();
        mcc.Dispose(true);
        this.Close();


        MessageBox.Show("Se descargaron las fotos correctamente" + " TOTAL: " + maximo);
        ProcessStartInfo s = new ProcessStartInfo();
        s.FileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
        s.UseShellExecute = false;
        Process.Start(s);
        Application.Exit();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sin el codigo no pudemos ayudarte. Incluye la infrmacion relevante

Comment: var listaPersona = service.GetPersona_SelectAll_Complete().Where(p => p.PersonaEstado == true).ToList();
                var listaImage = service.GetPersona_Select_Img_bytes().ToList();                                                          este es el codigo de laa consulta al servicio web cada consulta tiene mas de 3000 datos  y por ello al obtner el primer listado trae sin ningun problema y cuando pasa al al segun se cae la aplicacion

Comment: La verdad seria necesario que envíes una porción de código mas amplia para poder mirar otros factores que te puedan estar causando esto. Con lo poco que ofreces te puedo sugerir que el servicio después de la primer ejecución se esta cerrando (está ejecutando el método ´Dispose´) y cuando entra a evaluar la segunda vez este servicio ya no es accesible. Te recomiendo que para la segunda ejecución pruebes creando una nueva instancia del servicio por ej: ´service1.GetPersona_Select_Img_bytes().ToList();´

Comment: Pública en contenido de los métodos GetPersona_SelectAll_Complete y GetPersona_Select_Img_bytes para poder identificar el problema

Answer (score 0):

esto es codigo comlpleto - el error ocurre porque se aumento las datas al triple
por ello se cae, lo estoy desarrollando en un equipo windows movile divices supretrax atm, los dos estan marcados son los que tiene mas de 5000 datos juntos seria 10000,

try
            {
                ModuloAdministracionService service = new ModuloAdministracionService();

```
            service.Timeout = 999999999;

            cargar_empleados.Enabled = false;
            int maximo = 1;
            int EmpresaIDS = DCG.m.Common.Globales.EmpresaID;
            prog_datos_web.Value = 1;

            BMarcacion.Inicializa_Movil();

            var  listaComunicacion = service.GetComunicacionAll().ToList();
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
            var listaTipoEquipo = service.GetTipoEquiposAll().ToList();
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
            var listaTipoOperacion = service.GetTipoOperacionAll().ToList();
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
            var listaAccesos = service.GetAccesos().ToList();
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
            var listaUsuario = service.GetUsuarioAll().ToList();
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
            var listaDigitalizacionEmpresa = service.GetBusqueda_Documentos_Empresa_por_Vencer().ToList();
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
            var listaDigitalizacionPersona = service.GetBusqueda_Documentos_Persona_por_Vencer().ToList();
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
            var listaCategoria = service.GetCategoriasAll().ToList();
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
            var listaCargo = service.GetCargosAll().ToList();
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
            var listaEmpresa = service.GetEmpresaAllPersona().ToList();
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
            var listaEmpresaContratada = service.GetEmpresaAllContratdas().ToList();
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();
            var listaTerminal = service.GetTerminalesAll().ToList();

            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();

            **var listaPersona = service.GetPersona_SelectAll_Complete().Where(p => p.PersonaEstado == true).ToList();**
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();

            **var listaPersonaImagen = service.GetPersona_Select_Img_bytes();**
            service = new ModuloAdministracionService();

            int cantCom = listaComunicacion.Count;
            int cantTipE =  listaTipoEquipo.Count;
            int cantTipO = listaTipoOperacion.Count;
            int cantAcc =  listaAccesos.Count;
            int cantUsua =  listaUsuario.Count;
            int cantDigE =  listaDigitalizacionEmpresa.Count;
            int cantDigP =  listaDigitalizacionPersona.Count;
            int cantCat =  listaCategoria.Count;
            int cantCar =  listaCargo.Count;
            int cantEmp =  listaEmpresa.Count;
            int cantEmpc =  listaEmpresaContratada.Count;
            int cantTer = listaTerminal.Count;
            int cantPer = listaPersona.Count;

             maximo += cantCom + cantTipE + cantTipO + cantAcc + cantUsua + cantDigE + cantDigP+
                cantCat + cantCar + cantEmp + cantEmpc + cantTer + cantPer;
            prog_datos_web.Maximum = maximo +1;
            prog_datos_web.Minimum = 0;



            //insertar persona al sdf, en sql tienes q poner mas tiempo en respuesta puede modificar? si

            foreach (var item in listaPersona)
            {

                Persona p = new Persona();
                if (m.Common.Globales.todasLasEmpresaa == 0)
                {
                    if (item.EmpresaID == EmpresaIDS)
                    {
                        p.PersonaID = item.PersonaID;
                        p.PersonaCodigo = item.PersonaCodigo;
                        p.Descripcion1 = item.PersonaNombre;
                        p.Descripcion2 = item.PersonaApellidoPat + " " + item.PersonaApellidoMat;
                        p.PersonaTarjetaProximidad1 = item.PersonaTarjetaProximidad1;
                        p.PersonaTarjetaProximidad2 = item.PersonaTarjetaProximidad2;
                        //p.PersonaEstado = item.PersonaEstado.ToString();
                        p.CargoID = item.CargoID;
                        p.PersonaEstadoDigitalalizacion = item.PersonaEstadoDigitalizar;
                        p.TipoEntidadID = 1;
                        p.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;

                        BPersona.Insertar(p);
                        prog_datos_web.Value += 1;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    p.PersonaID = item.PersonaID;
                    p.PersonaCodigo = item.PersonaCodigo;
                    p.Descripcion1 = item.PersonaNombre;
                    p.Descripcion2 = item.PersonaApellidoPat + " " + item.PersonaApellidoMat;
                    p.PersonaTarjetaProximidad1 = item.PersonaTarjetaProximidad1;
                    p.PersonaTarjetaProximidad2 = item.PersonaTarjetaProximidad2;
                    p.CargoID = item.CargoID;
                    //p.PersonaEstado = item.PersonaEstado.ToString();
                    p.PersonaEstadoDigitalalizacion = item.PersonaEstadoDigitalizar;
                    p.TipoEntidadID = 1;
                    p.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;

                    BPersona.Insertar(p);
                    prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
                }


            }


            lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Persona registrada Correctamente";

            //insertar  EMPRESA CONTRATADA al sdf

            foreach (var item in listaEmpresaContratada)
            {
                if (m.Common.Globales.todasLasEmpresaa == 0)
                {
                    if (item.EmpresaID == EmpresaIDS)
                    {
                        EmpresaContratada emc = new EmpresaContratada();
                        emc.EmpresaContratadaID = item.EmpresaContratadaID;
                        emc.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
                        emc.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID = item.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID;
                        emc.EmpresaContratadaDigitalizacionEstado = item.EmpresaContradaDigitalizacionEstado;
                        emc.EmpresaCodigo = item.EmpresaCodigo;
                        emc.TipoEntidadID = 2;
                        //emc.EmpresaContratadaEstado = item.EmpresaContratadaEstado;
                        BEmpresaContrada.Insert_EmpresaContratada(emc);
                        prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    EmpresaContratada emc = new EmpresaContratada();
                    emc.EmpresaContratadaID = item.EmpresaContratadaID;
                    emc.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
                    emc.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID = item.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID;
                    emc.EmpresaContratadaDigitalizacionEstado = item.EmpresaContradaDigitalizacionEstado;
                    emc.TipoEntidadID = 2;

                    emc.EmpresaCodigo = item.EmpresaCodigo;
                    //emc.EmpresaContratadaEstado = item.EmpresaContratadaEstado;
                    BEmpresaContrada.Insert_EmpresaContratada(emc);
                    prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
                }

            }
            lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Empresa Contrada registrada Correctamente";
            // INSERT TERMINAL AL SDF
            foreach (var item in listaTerminal)
            {
                if (item.FabricanteID == 2)
                {
                    Terminal ter = new Terminal();
                    ter.TerminalID = item.TerminalID;
                    ter.TerminalCodigo = item.TerminalCodigo;
                    ter.TerminalDescripcion = item.TerminalDescripcion;
                    ter.TipoEquipoID = item.TipoEquipoID;
                    ter.TerminalID = item.TerminalID;
                    ter.Puerto = item.Puerto;
                    ter.AccesoID = item.AccesoID;
                    ter.FabricanteID = item.FabricanteID;
                    ter.ComunicacionID = item.ComunicacionID;
                    ter.TipoOperacionID = item.TipoOperacionID;
                    BTerminal.Insertar_Terminal(ter);
                    prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
                }

            }
            lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Persona registrada Terminal";
            //insertar  EMPRESA al sdf

            foreach (var item in listaEmpresa)
            {
                Empresa em = new Empresa();
                em.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
                em.EmpresaCodigo = item.EmpresaCodigo;
                em.EmpresaNombre = item.EmpresaNombre;
                em.CategoriaID = item.CategoriaID;
                BEmpresa.Insert_Empresa(em);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }
            // INSERT CI¡OMUNICACION AL SDF
            foreach (var item in listaComunicacion)
            {

                Comunicacion com = new Comunicacion();
                com.ComunicacionID = item.ComunicacionID;
                com.ComunicacionDescripcion = item.ComunicacionDescripcion;

                BComunicacion.Insert_Comunicacion(com);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }
            // INSERT CARGO AL SDF
            foreach (var item in listaCargo)
            {

                Cargos com = new Cargos();
                com.CargoID = item.CargoID;
                com.CargoDescripcion = item.CargoDescripcion;

                BCargo.Insert_Cargos(com);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }
            // INSERT CATEGORIA AL SDF
            foreach (var item in listaCategoria)
            {

                Categoria com = new Categoria();
                com.CategoriaID = item.CategoriaID;
                com.CategoriaDescripcion = item.CategoriaDescripcion;

                BCategoria.Insertar_Categoria(com);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }

            lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Comunicacion registrada Correctamente";
            // INSERT TipoEquipo AL SDF
            foreach (var item in listaTipoEquipo)
            {

                TipoEquipo tipe = new TipoEquipo();
                tipe.TipoEquipoID = item.TipoEquipoID;
                tipe.TipoEquipoDescripcion = item.TipoEquipoDescripcion;

                BTipoEquipo.Insert_TipoEquipo(tipe);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }
            lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Tipo Equipo registrada Correctamente";
            // INSERT TipoOperacion AL SDF
            foreach (var item in listaTipoOperacion)
            {

                TipoOperacion tipoo = new TipoOperacion();
                tipoo.TipoOperacionID = item.TipoOperacionID;
                //tipoo.TipoOperacionCodigo = item.TipoOperacionCodigo;
                tipoo.TipoOperacionDescripcion = item.TipoOperacionDescripcion;
                tipoo.TipoOperacionEstado = item.TipoOperacionEstado;

                BTipoOperacion.Insert_TipoOperacion(tipoo);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }
            lbl_estado_registro.Text = "TipoOperacion registrada Correctamente";
            // INSERT Accesos AL SDF
            foreach (var item in listaAccesos)
            {

                Accesos acc = new Accesos();
                acc.AccesoID = item.AccesoID;
                acc.AccesoDescripcion = item.AccesoDescripcion;
                BAccesos.Insert_Accesos(acc);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }
            lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Accesos registrada Correctamente";
            // INSERT DigitalizacionEmpresa AL SDF
            foreach (var item in listaDigitalizacionEmpresa)
            {

                DigitalizacionEmpresa dem = new DigitalizacionEmpresa();
                dem.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
                dem.EmpresaContratadaID = item.EmpresaContratadaID;
                dem.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID = item.EmpresaContratadaIDEmpresaID;
                dem.DocumentoEmpresaDescripcion = item.DocumentoEmpresaDescripcion;
                dem.DocumentoEmpresaID = item.DocumentoEmpresaID;
                //dem.CategoriaID = item.CategoriaID;
                dem.RegistroID = item.RegistroID;
                dem.Observacion = item.Observacion;
                dem.DiaRestante = item.DiaRestante;

                BDigitalizacionEmpresa.Insert_DigitalizacionEmpresa(dem);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }
            lbl_estado_registro.Text = "DigitalizacionEmpresa registrada Correctamente";
            // INSERT TipoOperacion AL SDF
            foreach (var item in listaDigitalizacionPersona)
            {

                DigitalizacionPersona dper = new DigitalizacionPersona();
                dper.PersonaID = item.PersonaID;
                dper.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
                dper.DocumentoPersonaID = item.DocumentoPersonaID;
                dper.DocumentoPersonaDescripcion = item.DocumentoPersonaDescripcion;
                //dper.CategoriaID = item.CategoriaID;
                dper.RegistroID = item.RegistroID;
                dper.Observacion = item.Observacion;
                dper.DiaRestante = item.DiaRestante;

                BDigitalizacionPersona.Insert_DigitalizacionPersona(dper);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }
            lbl_estado_registro.Text = "DigitalizacionPersona registrada Correctamente";
            // INSERT TipoOperacion AL SDF

            foreach (var item in listaUsuario)
            {

                Usuario usu = new Usuario();
                usu.UsuarioID = item.UsuarioID;
                usu.EmpresaID = item.EmpresaID;
                usu.UsuarioNombre = item.UsuarioNombre;
                usu.UsuarioPassword = item.UsuarioPassword;
                usu.UsuarioLogin = item.UsuarioLogin;
                usu.UsuarioEmail = item.UsuarioEmail;


                BUsuario.Insertar_Cuenta_Usuario(usu);
                prog_datos_web.Value += 1;
            }

            lbl_estado_registro.Text = "Todas las tablas registrada Correctamente";

            MessageBox.Show("Todas las tablas registrada Correctamente");
            SC_ConfiguracionSDF mcc = new SC_ConfiguracionSDF();
            mcc.Dispose(true);
            this.Close();


            MessageBox.Show("Se descargaron las fotos correctamente" + " TOTAL: " + maximo);
            ProcessStartInfo s = new ProcessStartInfo();
            s.FileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
            s.UseShellExecute = false;
            Process.Start(s);
            Application.Exit();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```